# Semantic UI integration in laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, http-status-code-404, semantic-ui, laravel-5.6

**Before I state my problem I have done the following:**

I've followed everything stated in the [Getting started](https://semantic-ui.com/introduction/getting-started.html) and installed the framework in my laravel project. Also I refereed to the answer [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/elixir/semantic-ui-integration) and made a quick search on stackoverflow but couldn't find a solution.

Now the problem is that I can't include *semantic.min.css* and semantic.min.js in my page because **it's not found**. I need someone to help me with the right instructions to use semantic ui in my 5.6 laravel project.

This my HTML code so far:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Gym Management</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset("semantic/dist/semantic.min.css") }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset("semantic/dist/semantic.min.js") }}"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="ui container">
HELLO
</div>
```

webpack.mix.js

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .copy('node_modules/semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css','public/css/semantic.min.css')
   .copy('node_modules/semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.js','public/js/semantic.min.js');
```

A snapshot when I inspect the page.
[image: inspection snapshot]

Answer (score 0):

Mostly i am getting this error because of wrong path. check your path twice carefully. Your "semantic" folder which has js and css files must be within public folder.

Comment: I need to find a way to link the css files in public. I can't just put them in public without the other related files of semantic UI.